# Tags, subtitles, records and subtotals using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I use a report based on a list. This list contains of three elements:

Subtitle
Records
Subtotals
and so on...

And each row have a tag for formatting:

```
H Subtitle
R Record
S Subtotal
```

.

### **The old way - Two step solution**

First I create a list of unique codes based on records

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (rec_code) rec_code FROM records
```

Then I loop this "list" in my frontend tool and fetch records for each code

```
SELECT * FROM records where rec_code=list.rec_code
```

This is a rather simple approach to get the job done, but it is slow.

.

### **Searching for a new way - ONE step**

The closest I have come is to mimic subtotals. But still subtitles and tags are missing

```
select rec_code, rec_sum
    from (
    select rec_code, 'name' as name, rec_sum, rec_code as o
    from rec as a
    union all
    select 'Subtotal', 'name' as name, sum(rec_sum), rec_code as o
    from rec as a
    group by rec_code
    ) as a
order by o, rec_sum
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/270d6/10

This is the wanted output from this sqlfiddle

```
H code a
R A         1
R A         2
S Subtotal  3

H code b
R B         3
R B         3
S Subtotal  6
```

Is this possible? And how?

Thank you in advance for any clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with codes as (
    select *
    from rec
    join code on rec_code = code_id
    )
select tag, cname, rec_sum
from (
    select code_name, 'R' tag, rec_code cname, rec_sum
    from codes
    union all
    select distinct on (code_id) code_name, 'H' tag, code_name, null
    from codes
    union all
    select code_name, 'S' tag, 'Subtotal', sum(rec_sum)
    from codes
    group by 1
    order by 1,2
    ) sub
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/270d6/27)

Comment: Thank you! On the right track, but all records are not there. When I replaced UNION with UNION ALL all records showed up, but the subtitles was double. How do I fix this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/270d6/3

Answer (score 1):

You should really do this formatting at the application layer.  But, you can put together a SQL query that comes closer.  [For instance](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/270d6/16):

```
select rec_code, rec_sum
from (
    select rec_code, 'name' as name, rec_sum, rec_code as o, 2 as o2
    from rec as a
    union all
    select 'Subtotal', 'name' as name, sum(rec_sum), rec_code as o, 2 as o2
    from rec as a
    group by rec_code
    union all
    select code_name, 'header' as name, NULL, code_id as o, 1 as o2
    from code
) a
order by o, o2, rec_sum;
```

Comment: Letting Postgresql do the stuff can reduce the executing time to fractions of a second compared to several minutes. It may turns out that you are correct, but I will try.